# oracle mobile server - load specific user data on android device while syncing

Tags: android, oracle

How to load specific user data from oracle mobile server to android device. I am following below example URL and implemented code to my application.
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E22663_01/doc.11100/e22681/sandroid.htm

Now sync process working fine but it syncs all the users data to each device, while I want to load data of user who is currently logged in.

Thanks